# Как ускорить запрос в базу?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Ребята, вот в чем суть, есть таблица пользователей на несколько миллионов `user` так же есть таблица `orders`  и `users_to_orders`

`SELECT total FROM users
LEFT JOIN users_to_orders ON users.id = users_to_orders.id_user 
LEFT JOIN ordersON users_to_orders.id_orders = orders.id
GROUP BY firstname DESC LIMIT 0,500`

запрос выполняется миллионы лет тип таблиц "MyISAM", так же стоят все индексы, как максимально сократить время выборки результата и выбрать 10 пользователей с максимальным суммарным тоталом?

в таблице users и orders индекс это id 
в таблице users_to_orders индексы id_orders и id_user

Comment: группировку по id делать + кеширование + InnoDB

Comment: опишите все индексы в вопросе, которые у вас есть, а то "стоят все" как-то не поможет делу

Comment: Могли бы Вы описать как сделать группировку и кеширование, разве InnoDB поможет, т.е. сделать связи?

Answer (score 1):

1. Нужно делать группировку по индексу. Численному. Все строки плохо индексируются B+-деревьями, по определению.

   `SELECT * FROM (
       SELECT U.id as user_id, count(O.id) as total FROM users AS U
       LEFT JOIN users_to_orders AS UO ON U.id = UO.id_user 
       LEFT JOIN orders AS O ON UO.id_orders = O.id 
       GROUP BY U.id DESC
   ) AS P1 INNER JOIN users AS P2 ON P1.user_id = P2.id 
   ORDER BY P1.total DESC LIMIT 0, 500;`
2. Нужно кеширование делать. Вам нужны 500 результатов - обновляйте их раз  в `N` секунд. Например, может помочь временная таблица aka materialized view (да, их можно эмулировать по триггеру).
3. InnoDb. Тут все просто.

Comment: #1054 - Неизвестный столбец 'u.user_id' в 'field list' вот такую ошибку получил

Comment: Поправил, но дальше концепт должен быть понятен. Правьте по вашему усмотрению.

Comment: Если честно то не очень понятен о5 получилась ошибка #1054 - Неизвестный столбец 'P2.user_id' в 'on clause'

Comment: Обновил, но без явно указанной схемы не просто запросы писать.

Comment: Спасибо но запрос все равно 164.9748 сек. и как пользователей с максимальным суммарным тоталом?

Comment: При многомиллионных выборках такое время адекватно. Используйте кеширование. Запрос уже подходит для этой задачи. Индексы users_to_orders сделаны по отдельности и композитно?

Comment: "Запрос уже подходит для этой задачи." Total получается 54 максимум хотя там значения от 5 тыс

Comment: добавил еще WHERE stat = 'done' и все перестало работать

Answer (score 0):

Вам надо сначала убедиться, что узкое место именно в DB. У меня тоже в одном проекте есть до 1 млн записей, но работает весьма шустро.

Есть подозрение, что дело не таблицах. Вам надо натыкать везде логи, и найти узкое место - где больше всех задержка.

Если окажется, что проблема в таблицах.

1) Одно из самое главных используем InnoDb. MyISAM намного медленнее, там даже 
блокировка на уровне таблиц, а не строк.

2) Все таблицы необходимо привести к 3-ей нормальной форме. Чтобы поиск был исключительно по цифрам (они быстрее обрабатываются чем строки).

3) Скорее всего миллион записей тоже можно разбить на определенные кластеры. Если да, лучше сделать больше табличек меньшего размера.